# How to convert Encrypted NSData into plain text string

Tags: cocoa, encryption, aes

I'm taking a user inputted NSString, converting it to NSData with NSUTF8StringEncoding. I'm then using CCCrypt to encrypt that data using a random salt and IV and a user inputted password.

My question is, how do I convert this encrypted NSData into a format that could be decrypted by a plain text AES decryptor such as http://www.everpassword.com/aes-encryptor?

Furthermore, does CCCrypt automatically add the salt & rounds to the encrypted data? Or do I need to manually add them in some way before the data can be decrypted with access only to the secret password?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your goal really to support online AES decryptors? If not, then there are many options you could pursue for encrypting data securely. I recommend Rob Napier's [RNCryptor](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor/wiki). Please also share your code if you want specific help.

Comment: I'm not at the computer that has the code on at the moment, but I will post it when I am. My goal is to have the encrypted data being put into a .txt email attachment that the recipient can then open, copy the code to and online AES decryptor and then use the passkey to read.

Comment: OK, but what about my first question - what are you really asking for here?

Comment: At the moment, the app uses this method to send data, I just need the data in the attachment to be more secure. Thanks for your help\

Comment: Basically, what is the best way to send the encrypted NSData via email , and how would the recipient decrypt it to a readable format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website you posted uses [Gibberish-aes](https://github.com/mdp/gibberish-aes) and giberish aes uses an openssl compatible format. CCCrypt will not give you that format by itself, however you don't have to do it yourself. [RNCryptor](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor) happens to have an OpenSSL format mode `RNOpenSSLEncryptor`.